# PHP JSON_DECODE remove double quotes in double quotes?

Tags: php, decode, json

I'm using the hackernews api from http://api.ihackernews.com/. I'm getting the results via JSON.

I'm having problems with the php function json_decode(). It works fine, except if there is to many double quotes.

The error is with
`"Ask PG: Will you post an update to "StartupIdeasWeu0027dLiketoFund"?"` in:

```
{
 "title": "Ask PG: Will you post an update to "StartupIdeasWeu0027dLiketoFund"?",
 "url": "/comments/6014422",
 "id": 6014422,
 "commentCount": 58,
 "points": 214,
 "postedAgo": "12 hours ago",
 "postedBy": "awwstn"
}
```

How can I replace `"Ask PG: Will you post an update to "StartupIdeasWeu0027dLiketoFund"?"` with `"Ask PG: Will you post an update to \"StartupIdeasWeu0027dLiketoFund\"?"`?

Comment: PHP's json_decode works well. In this case your data is not JSON compliant.

Comment: You aren't running stripslashes() over the input, are you?

Comment: @MikeW Theres nothing I can do, as I don't control the data provided by the api.

Comment: @PleaseStand No, I get the page via CURL, and then I run the data through json_decode()

Comment: That JSON is not valid, period. If you're not munging it, the API is basically broken.

Comment: Reading the comments on that API's page... yeah, it seems very broken.

Comment: @ChrisMaher FWIW Chris, I took a look at the data being emitted by the API. The stuff I saw _is_ being escaped properly. My best suggestion is a Regex, but it'll be tricky, particularly if the problem on the API is intermittent.